# How to find number of simple non-isomorphic graphs for a given sequence?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Suppose a sequence of degree of vertices of a graph is given.How to find total number of graphs for the given sequence.For example if sequence (2,2,2,2,2,2) is given , then two possible graphs are - 1.Hexagon 2.Two triangles not connected to each other.So i can tell that given sequence has at least two distinct graphs.
But without drawing graphs randomly , how to know total  number of distinct graphs for given sequence.

Comment: { 2,2,2,2,2,2} = {2} is not a sequence.  It is a set.   The ordered six-tuple (2,2,2,2,2,2) is like a sequence.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Sorry .That was typing error .Now i have edited the answer.

Comment: It is an even an open problem to count $p$-regular graphs on $n$ vertices (graphs with a degree sequence of $p$ repeated $n$ times). See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77730/how-many-p-regular-graphs-with-n-vertices-are-there for some asymptotic results.